# Mirametrix S2 gaze tracker: Sending general purpose input (GPI) values always fails

Tags: python, xml, eye-tracking

I'm using the Mirametrix S2 gaze tracking device. In the API docs (v1.1), it says that the `ENABLE_SEND_GPI` command allows a tracking client to insert data into the gaze stream. Copying some of the example code, I tried the following:

```
sock.send('<SET ID="ENABLE_SEND_GPI" STATE="1" />\r\n')
sock.send('<SET ID="GPI_NUMBER" VALUE="1" />\r\n')
sock.send('<SET ID="GPI1" VALUE="INTERVAL" />\r\n')
```

I get the following in response:

```
<ACK ID="ENABLE_SEND_GPI" STATE="1" />
<ACK ID="GPI_NUMBER" VALUE="1" />
<ACK ID="GPI1" ERR="Invalid GPI ID" />
```

I've tried many different combinations of ids, but the only ones that get a response are `GPI1` through `GPI10`, and each one is rejected for `Invalid GPI ID`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mirametrix got back to me. It appears it is a bug in their tracker software. They have a patch coming out.